# Inspect Joomla template/theme name

Tags: templates, cms

I am working on a Joomla site and I want the make the design similar to the following website:

```
www.habibrafiq.com/index.php
```

How can I inspect the template/theme name ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply open your browser inspector by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>

Go to view the source code, and open the `<head>` tag which will display a load of stylesheets and scripts.

Here's a screenshot to show you:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

http://www.habibrafiq.com/templates/habibrafiq/templateDetails.xml

The template was made by http://www.itchamber.com/ probably using some previous template as a base.

Also that looks like Joomla! 1.5, so you can't really gain much from knowing the template name.